# How might I be able to write multiple function definitions for multiple types in a polymorphic manner in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

Given my type definitions:

```hs
data Tile = Revealed | Covered deriving (Eq, Show)
data MinePit = Clean | Unsafe deriving (Eq, Show)
data Flag = Flagged | Unflagged deriving (Eq, Show)
type Square = (Tile, MinePit, Flag)
type Board = [[Square]]
```

I created two functions:

1. **createBoard** generates a 2D list of tuples of values -- or a *'Board'*. It initialises a list of dimension n*m all of the same value.

```hs
createBoard :: Int -> Int -> Board
createBoard 0 _ = [[]]
createBoard _ 0 = [[]]
createBoard 1 1 = [[(Covered, Clean, Unflagged)]]
createBoard n m = take n (repeat (take m (repeat (Covered, Clean, Unflagged))))
```

An example:

```
λ> createBoard 2 3
[[(Covered,Clean,Unflagged),(Covered,Clean,Unflagged),(Covered,Clean,Unflagged)],[(Covered,Clean,Unflagged),(Covered,Clean,Unflagged),(Covered,Clean,Unflagged)]]
```

2. A function **defineIndices** was defined for the purpose of an in order list of indices for Board(s) produced by createBoard.

```hs
defineIndices :: Int -> Int -> [[(Int,Int)]]
defineIndices n m = [[(i,j) | j <- [1..m]] | i <- [1..n]]
```

It behaves like:

```hs
λ> defineIndices 2 3
[[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)],[(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)]]
```

From here, I have created a function to create a **MapBoard**, where the values of a particular Square could be looked up given its indicies.

```hs
type MapBoard = Map (Int, Int) Square

createMapBoard :: [[(Int,Int)]] -> [[Square]] -> MapBoard
createMapBoard indices squares = M.fromList $ zip (concat indices) (concat squares)
```

However, it seemed reasonable to me that I should also write a method in which I can create a MapBoard directly from a pair of Int(s), implementing my prior functions. This might look like:

```hs
createMapBoard2 :: Int -> Int -> MapBoard
createMapBoard2 n m = createMapBoard indices squares where
  indices = defineIndices n m
  squares = createBoard n m
```

However, I looked up as to whether it is possible achieve polymorphism in this situataion with createMapBoard, and have createMapBoard2 be instead createMapBoard. I discovered [online](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Polymorphism#Ad-hoc_polymorphism) that this is called Ad-Hoc Polymorphism, and one can do e.g.

```hs
class Square a where
    square :: a -> a
    
instance Square Int where
    square x = x * x

instance Square Float where
    square x = x * x
```

Attempting to write something similar myself, the best I could come up with is the following:

```hs
class MyClass a b MapBoard where
  createMapBoard :: a -> b -> MapBoard

instance createMapBoard [[(Int,Int)]] -> [[Square]] -> MapBoard where
  createMapBoard indices squares = M.fromList $ zip (concat indices) (concat squares)

instance createMapBoard Int -> Int -> MapBoard where
  createMapBoard n m = createMapBoard indices squares where
  indices = defineIndices n m
  squares = createBoard n m
```

Attempting to compile this results in a Compilation error:

```
src/minesweeper.hs:35:19-26: error: …
    Unexpected type ‘MapBoard’
    In the class declaration for ‘MyClass’
    A class declaration should have form
      class MyClass a b c where ...
   |
Compilation failed.
λ>
```

I am confused as to why I am not allowed to use a non-algebraic type such as MapBoard in the class definition.

```hs
class MyClass a b MapBoard where
```

Replacing MapBoard with another algebraic type c brings about another compilation error, which is lost on me.

```
src/minesweeper.hs:37:10-63: error: …
    Illegal class instance: ‘createMapBoard [[(Int, Int)]]
                             -> [[Square]] -> MapBoard’
      Class instances must be of the form
        context => C ty_1 ... ty_n
      where ‘C’ is a class
   |
src/minesweeper.hs:39:10-46: error: …
    Illegal class instance: ‘createMapBoard Int -> Int -> MapBoard’
      Class instances must be of the form
        context => C ty_1 ... ty_n
      where ‘C’ is a class
   |
Compilation failed.
```

Is it possible for me to achieve the ad-hoc polymorphism of createMapBoard? Am I able to create a class definition which has a strict constraint that the return type must be MapBoard for all instances?

**Edit:**

Having corrected the syntactic errors, my code is now:

```hs
class MyClass a b where
  createMapBoard :: a -> b
instance createMapBoard [[(Int,Int)]] [[Square]] where
  createMapBoard indices squares = M.fromList $ zip (concat indices) (concat squares)
instance createMapBoard Int Int where
  createMapBoard n m = createMapBoard indices squares where
  indices = defineIndices n m
  squares = createBoard n m
```

This leads to yet another compilation error:

```
src/minesweeper.hs:37:10-23: error: …
    Not in scope: type variable ‘createMapBoard’
   |
src/minesweeper.hs:39:10-23: error: …
    Not in scope: type variable ‘createMapBoard’
   |
Compilation failed.
```

I am inclined to believe that an error in my understanding of classes is still present.

Comment: You simply should not use a third parameter, it is `class MyClass a b where`. These are the only variables in the functions the typeclass exports.

Comment: for the instance `a` and `b` are `Int`s, so `instance createMapBoard Int Int where`.

Comment: please [edit] the question.

Comment: Just so you know, this is a terrible use of class-based polymorphism. Yes, there are situations where somewhat ad hoc polymorphism makes sense, but that's usually within some more systematic context.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the question has been edited as requested having implemented the changes. I am still having difficulties (and confusion) in attempting to achieve ad hoc polymorphism.

A number of users also suggested that this was a poor use case of ad hoc polymorphism. This might be so, however I would like to learn how to do ad hoc polymorphism for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to write it this way:

```
class MyClass a b where createMapBoard :: a -> b -> MapBoard

instance MyClass [[(Int,Int)]] [[Square]] where
    createMapBoard indices squares = M.fromList $ zip ...

instance MyClass Int Int where
    createMapBoard n m = createMapBoard indices squares where
        ...
```

The `... -> ... -> MapBoard` is already in the `createMapBoard` method's signature, this doesn't belong in the class / instance heads.

Incidentally, I'm not convinced that it really makes sense to have a class here at all. There's nothing wrong with having two separately named `createMapBoard` functions. A class only is the way to go if you can actually write polymorphic functions over it, but in this case I doubt it – you'd rather have either the concrete situation where you need the one version, or the other. There's no need for a class then, just hard-write which version it is you want.

One reason for rather going with separate functions than a class method is that it makes the type checker's work easier. As soon as the arguments of `createMapBoard` are polymorphic, they could potentially have *any* type (at least as far as the type checker is concerned). So you can only call it with arguments whose type is fully determined elsewhere. Now, in other programming languages the type of values you might want to pass is generally fixed anyway, but in Haskell it's actually extremely common to have also *polymorphic values*. The simplest example is number literals – they don't have type `Int` or so, but `Num a => a`.

I personally find “reverse polymorphism” normally nicer to work with than “forward polymorphism”: don't make the *arguments* to functions polymorphic, but rather the *results*. This way, it's enough to have the outermost type of an expression fixed by the environment, and automatically all the subexpressions are inferred by the type checker. The other way around, you have to have all the individual expressions' types fixed, and the compiler can infer the final result type... which is hardly useful because you probably want to fix that by a signature anyway.

Comment: (Or if you're doing something like variadic functions or other significant class-based programming.)

Comment: You mention that it does not this sort of polymorphism might not be appropriate here. Another user said something similar. My understanding is that such polymorphism makes sense in programming languages if two or more functions are intended to produce the same thing, right? Is it not desirable to the flexibility to be achieve the same outcome whether or not the indices or the Board have already been initialised?
@dfeuer if possible, I would be interested to hear your thoughts on this too as your sentiments were along the same lines.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Surely those instance declarations should be `instance MyClass [[(Int,Int)]] [[Square]] where createMapBoard = ...`, rather than `instance createMapBoard [[(Int,Int)]] [[Square]] where ...`?

Comment: @EoinDowling Nah, two functions merely producing the same thing isn't a good enough reason to name them the same thing. We don't try to make `abs` and `length` have the same name, even though they both produce an `Int`.

Comment: @EoinDowling, we mostly prefer to keep even our "ad hoc" polymorphism principled. As a rule, a class method should have a single *meaning* shared across all instances. Exceptions to this rule are occasionally useful for getting the compiler to write code for you, and for some very fancy embedded domain-specific languages, but beginners should generally steer clear of such things, and even advanced users rarely write them.

Comment: @EoinDowling: Even though Haskell type classes provide mostly the same functionality as traits in Rust or Scala, you'll notice that they are used in different ways. The main difference I've gathered, so far, is that Haskellers like that their type classes have widely applicable, mathematical properties. E.g. `Semigroup`, `Bounded`. Where traits are used more as Java-like interfaces for anything.

Comment: @EoinDowling, probably the most generally interesting less-principled use of typeclasses is for "tagless final" encodings of languages, where a *class* represents a language, each *method* represents a piece of abstract syntax, and each *instance* represents an "interpretation" of the language (e.g., for evaluation, compilation, or pretty-printing).